# Freeing JavaScript's ActiveXObject()?

Tags: c#, javascript, com, release, activexobject

I'm calling a C# COM component using javascript: `keystore = new ActiveXObject("RBCrypto.KeyStore");`. I've noticed this instance stays around until I exit the browser. Is there anyway to "release" that object when the user leaves the page? Currently i'm using:

```
window.onunload=function() //when a user leaves the page close the keystore
{
     if(keystore != null)
     {
         try
         {
            keystore.closeKeyStore(); //method in keystore
            delete keystore;
         }
         catch(err) { alert(err.description); }
     }  
}
```

But the COM object is still hangin around. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's a little late to respond. "Before late than never"

I think the correct is "Application.Quit();". However, the Application of object COM/OLE/ActiveX can return null. I do not know how to do return Application != null to run the Quit();

You can try...

```
try
{
    keystore.closeKeyStore();
    delete keystore;
    keystore = null;
    CollectGarbage(); 
}
catch(err)
{
    alert('freeing ActiveXObject via javascript'+ err.description);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try,

```
keystore.Application.Quit();
```

This result is from http://www.c-point.com/javascript_tutorial/jsobjActiveXObject.htm

you can also try nulling all the object attached values before delete

```
for (k in elm) {
            try {
                elm[k] = null;
            }
            catch (e) {
            }
        }
}
```

I have found this helps in the case of HTML objects that have not been delete, and have various objects attached to them.